# Passing $_GET variable through URL throws undefined index

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to redirect from JS and include a variable that will be accessible via  $_GET for PHP, like so:

```
let destination = "viewmode.php?id=" + id
window.location.href = destination;
```

Once I get to the PHP in the other page, this

```
print $_GET['id'];
```

Only raises error "Undefined index: id"

From the url I can tell that the variable exists... right?

```
...ne/viewmode.php?id=7
```

So,

1- Is it okay to pass a variable simply by modifying the url in JS?

2- Does PHP's $_GET method simply rely on the url to access the requested values?

If the answer to #2 is yes, then why can't PHP find the index "id"?

PS: I know I should be using `if(isset($_GET['id'])` once I'm done debugging

Comment: If `if(isset($_GET['id'])) {` yields false it wouldn't hit the code which causes the warning. Your looking in the wrong place or this is not the code.

Comment: That question only says I should check that the variable isset() and that "For $_POST and $_GET you just have to check if the index exists or not before you use them", that is pretty much my question, since I can see it in the URL, can't I assume it is set?

Comment: How about `var_dump($_GET);` before your `print $_GET['id'];` line? Where exactly do you see that error; on the page itself or somewhere else like the browser console?

Comment: var_dump($_GET); throws the same error, Phil.
(thx)

Comment: All variable should be declared and checked before use, in any language. php is just loosely typed, so it throws warning instead of fatal errors.

Comment: @FelDev that is quite literally impossible. `var_dump($_GET)` should not throw any errors. At a minimum, it would display `array(0) { }`

Comment: @Phil you are very right!
it does display array(0) { }

Comment: So, where exactly do you see that error; on the page itself or somewhere else like the browser console? Does you server have any URL rewriting enabled (like in a `.htaccess` file)? Try `var_dump($_SERVER);`, that will contain a lot of useful information.

Comment: The error is in the console, looking up `var_dump($_SERVER);` right now...

Comment: Right, so if it's in the console, it's probably coming from an AJAX request. PHP doesn't usually write to the browser console. Somewhere, you have another request to `viewmode.php` that does not include the query parameter. You should be able to clearly see it in your browser's *Network* console

Comment: @Phil, thanks a lot, I'll look for that.

Answer (score -1):

Try using $_REQUEST['id'], I think this is what you are after.